# Is the character table of $S_3$ unique?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to construct the character table of $S_3$ group.

| $n_c$ | class | $1$ | $\bar{1}$ | $2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $I$ | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | $(12),(23),(13)$ | 1 | a | b |
| 2 | $(123),(132)$ | 1 | c | d |

As a brute force method, I imposed every column & row orthogonality:
\begin{equation}
\sum_c n_c\chi^{(r)*}(c)\chi^{s}(c)=N(G)\delta^{rs}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_r \chi^{(r)*}(c)\chi^{s}(c')=\frac{N(G)}{n_c}\delta^{cc'}
\end{equation}
There are total 10 equations with 4 unknowns. Okay, although it might be redundant, it can be solved in principle. But Mathematica found two roots!

[image: Two solutions found.]

How can it be possible, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want it is done here :) https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Determination_of_character_table_of_symmetric_group:S3 It uses the fact that $a$ and $c$ are roots of the unity

Comment: I see. Since it is 1-dimensional representation, the characters must be $\pm 1$. But I wonder isn't is possible to fully construct the table using only orthogonality relations above?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with group theory but I just want to pose a question - what if we accept the first solution? Could this lead to a new area of Mathematics?

Comment: @VeselinDimov no, it was more of a necessary condition but not sufficient. Here characters are morphisms from $S_3$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$, characters have to verify additional properties that exclude this possibility

Comment: @Mr.Anomaly To your statement that the 1dim. irre must have character $\pm 1$: the character could be a phase ( as in an Abelian group of order $3$ for instance) but the irreps of $S_n$ only have real characters so this eliminates this option.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You're right. I missed that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters of a finite group take values in algebraic integers (being sums of roots of unity). There are stronger results for symmetric groups in particular, but that's enough to eliminate the first solution above.